# Virtual Inheritance Base Constructor Mechanics (Diamond Problem) Clarification

Tags: c++, class, constructor, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

The Diamond Problem and Virtual Inheritance are topics that have been discussed endlessly, though while researching them I found myself still uncertain of a few specifics when it comes to calling Base constructors due to the large variety of ways the same terminology was used in different places.

I understood that in the typical Diamond inheritance setup it is the responsibility of the most derived, concrete class to explicitly call the constructor of the base class that is virtually inherited from, lest a default constructor be called (if available); however, I wanted to know exactly what this meant for the constructors of the "middle" classes in the case where the base class does not/cannot have a default constructor.

I did a basic test of this case and would like to confirm that I now correctly understand my findings, just to make sure there are no gotchyas or misconceptions I have.

Note the following code is cutdown to just focus on constructor calls and doesn't demonstrate why I need a diamond inheritance tree in the first place.

```
class Base
{
private:
    std::string mString;

protected:
    Base(std::string str) : mString(str) {}

public:
    void identify() { std::cout << mString << std::endl; }
};

class DerivedA : public virtual Base
{
public:
    DerivedA(std::string str) : Base(str) {}
};

class DerivedB : public virtual Base
{
public:
    DerivedB(std::string str) : Base(str) {}
};

class Concrete : public DerivedA, public DerivedB
{
public:
    Concrete(std::string str) :
        Base(str),
        DerivedA("not used"),
        DerivedB("not used")
    {}
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Concrete con("I am concrete");
    DerivedA derA("I am DerivedA");
    DerivedB derB("I am DerivedB");
    con.identify();
    derA.identify();
    derB.identify();
}

// Output:
// I am concrete
// I am DerivedA
// I am DerivedB
```

So am I correct in that what happens here is that although I have to call the Base constructor in both Derived classes because there is no default constructor, when Concrete is being constructed the instance of Base is created first via the call to its constructor in Concrete's initialization list, followed by the creation of Derived A and then Derived B; however, in their constructors the call of Base's constructor is ignored, and instead the instance of Base they need that would have resulted from that call is instead provided via a reference to the instance spawned from Concrete's initialization list?

Based on the output, it seems that due to the virtual inheritance the calls to Base's constructor within DerivedA/B's initialization list are only actually used if I instantiate a copy of them directly (which I may actually want to do at times, so this is indeed useful), otherwise the calls to the Base constructor in the most derived class essentially "override" the same constructor calls in the classes higher up the inheritance tree.

Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you understand everything correctly.

Comment: Yes. In the cases I have traced, it seems like the most derived class passes a hidden "I have already fixed the virtual bases"-flag to its direct parents. That makes them avoid calling the constructor again.

Comment: I don't know exactly what "diamond inheritance" means, but **virtual bases** are constructed by the constructor of the most-derived class.

Comment: @PeteBecker I meant that the inheritance tree in this example is the same as in the classical Diamond Problem. Thanks, for the clarification.

BoP Thanks for the insight of your experimentation